# Does my Retrofit/ReactiveX method actually retrieve data asynchronously?

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, reactivex

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
 swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
 retrieveData(mCardAdapter, db);
});
```

For some reason the following method is blocking my main UI thread, but it should be running in the background. For example, the refresh indicator hangs when I run `retrieveData()`. If I initialize a progress dialog before running, it also hangs and I can't scroll through my RecyclerView. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here?

```
public void retrieveData(final CardAdapter mCardAdapter, SQLiteHelper db) {
 CausticRetrofitService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(CausticRetrofitService.class, CausticRetrofitService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
 service.getMedia()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Subscriber < MediaResponse > () {
   @Override
   public final void onCompleted() {

    Log.e("CausticRetrofitService", "Caustic Request Completed!");

    /* Cancel all progress indicators after data retrieval complete */
    setRefreshingFalse();

    // TODO: Add media to local data store and then display them one-by-one in real-time
    mCardAdapter.addData(db.getAllMediaImages()); // Add all media images to card views
    Log.d(getClass().toString(), "Added to local database: " + db.getAllMediaImages());
    mCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   @Override
   public final void onError(Throwable e) {
    /* Cancel all progress indicators on data retrieval error */
    setRefreshingFalse();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot retrieve data. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("CausticRetrofitService", e.getMessage());
   }

   @Override
   public final void onNext(MediaResponse mediaResponse) {
    if (mediaResponse != null) {

     Log.e("CausticRetrofitService", "Returned objects: " + mediaResponse.getResults());

     for (String mediaId: mediaResponse.getResults()) {
      Log.e("CausticRetrofitService", mediaId);
     }

     List < String > mediaIds = mediaResponse.getResults();
     Log.d(getClass().toString(), "All Media IDs: " + mediaIds);

     if (mediaIds.isEmpty()) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot retrieve data. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     mCardAdapter.clear();
     mCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     /* Store objects from remote web service to local database */
     for (String mediaId: mediaIds) {
      // TODO: Why are these null?
      Log.d(getClass().toString(), "Media Id: " + mediaId);
      MediaImage newMediaImage = new MediaImage();
      newMediaImage.setTitle(mediaId);
      db.addMediaImage(newMediaImage); // Add media image to local database
     }

    } else {
     Log.e("CausticRetrofitService", "Object returned is null.");
    }

   }

  });
}
```

I'm thinking that adding the remote data to the local data store in the `onNext()` method might be the thing that's blocking, although I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network call is done in a new thread as you specified, but the Subscriber methods `onNext()` and `onComplete()` runs on the observing `Scheduler`, which is the main thread.

You seem to be doing some database operations on those, try to offload the caching also to the background thread using a `doOnNext()` operator.

What `doOnNext()` will do, is that it is called for each emission in your stream.

It can go something like that

```
service.getMedia()
  .doOnNext(data -> cacheData(data))
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Where `cacheData(`) is a method that does all your DB calls. And the only things left in your `onNext()` and `onComplete()` would be updating the UI only.